# runtime error coming while using gtk clipboard library in c++ code?

Tags: c++, gtk, clipboard

i am trying to use gtk clipboard library in my c++ code.
for that i am using the following statement in the code:

```
GtkClipboard *gtkCB = gtk_clipboard_get(GDK_SELECTION_CLIPBOARD);
```

The code is getting compiled successfully but at the runtime it is showing the following error:

```
(process:1531): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_clipboard_get_for_display:
assertion `display != NULL' failed
```

Can some one explain me this?? thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post code that actually replicated this problem, or at least showed the various declarations & definitions involved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `gtk_init` before your `gtk_clipboard_get`?

Short explanation: the display is related to the X11 display concept. It is the connection to the X11 server. You need it for clipboard operations, since X11 (ie. the Xorg server) is managing selections & clipboard.

The `gtk_init` routine (to be called at the very start of your program) is initializing the display (that is, connecting to Xorg, etc etc...).

Comment: gtk_init(NULL,NULL) at the beginning does the trick.